# Phpldapadmin does not work for an unknown reason

Tags: ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I'm trying to install LDAP. I've installed `slapd` and the PhpLDAPAdmin tool on Debian, but when I'm logged in, I cannot do anything. Despite I've logged in as `'cn=admin,dc=barbucha'`, I see on the right side instead of the tree:

```
Logged in as: dc=example,dc=com
   This base cannot be created with PLA.
```

I tried Google, but this error seems to be a rare one. I've created a database there is the `'cn=admin,dc=barbucha'` in. (Otherwise I could not use the name to log in.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happens quite rarely. From an unknown reason the configuring process didn't get data from the LDAP server and didn't set proper values in the `/etc/phpldapadmin/config.php` script. Somewhere near by line 300 were two important lines generated erroneously:

```
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=example,dc=com'));
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com');
```

These settings uses PhpLDAPAdmin to access LDAP datatase regardless to the login name you've been logged in with. To update these lines helped:

```
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=barbucha'));
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=barbucha');
```

Comment: maybe it's not that rare: it's enough to install phpldapadmin *before* slapd for example.

Comment: I faced this issue when I uninstalled my ldap server and re-installed with a different Base DN, thanks to your answer everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should add a LDAP root first:
create a file in /etc/openldap/

```
vim /etc/openldap/base.ldif
```

then input:

```
dn: dc=em,dc=com
o: RDCenter
objectclass: dcobject
objectclass: organization
```

and run this command in the directory:

```
ldapadd  -f base.ldif  -x -D  cn=Admin,dc=em,dc=com -W
```

Input your own password,and the root node would be added.
Reopen the phpldapadmin,you will find everything is well